# Neural network residuals plot analysis

Tags: neural-networks, residuals

I am new to neural networks, and i am interested in whether residual (standardized residuals vs. predicted values) plot should not form any pattern (ex.: correlated, U-shape) even in the case of neural networks (not just lin.reg.)? So is it worth to check whether the residual points distribution normally distributed around 0 mean? If so, does it mean no deterministic errors are captured?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! For what reason would you want to check the residuals of a linear regression? Do those reasons apply to your neural network modeling?

Comment: Thank You! I am just generally interested in the model accuracy analysis of neural networks (behaviour of the model). I don't know whether the condition of independent errors of lin reg. still holds for complex models like NN. So i don't know should i check the residual patterns in case of NN(?).

Comment: Let’s start simple: for what reasons would you want to check the residuals of a linear regression?

Comment: OK. I guess, maybe to check the linearity?

Comment: Is that part of the assumptions of a neural network? // What other reasons are there to look at the residuals?

Comment: No it's not an assumption of neural network. But i don't know what kind of other information can i get from the plot(?).

Comment: Focus on linear regression. Why would you look at the plot. Assessing linearity is one reason. Are there any others? Once you determine that, consider if those matter to your neural network.